Puzzle-based game-show with a bald host and themed rooms
A bald anchor
different theme-based rooms/locations
contestants had to find keys/diamonds etc within time-limit
In the end, on a stage; a large glass globe has many paper-chits hurled inside.  
eg.,
3D cube-maze
A room half-filled with water and participants in boats/canoes
etc.  
More like sophisticated 'Takeshi's castle'  
Saw it first in 1993 on Star TV (Fox maybe)...

The Crystal Maze. The bald host is Richard O'Brian. Awesome show. I was heart broken when it was cancelled.
